# SWIG ignores %mutable in class; how to work around?

Tags: python, c++, swig

Using SWIG 3.0.0 on Windows, exporting to python, I have the following interface file:

```
%module example

%immutable;

class MyClass {
 public:
%mutable;
  char *str1;
%immutable;
  char *str2;
};
```

My intent is to make the all class members in the whole file immutable (read-only) by default, but allow a few to be writable -- in this case str1.

But SWIG seems to ignore the %mutable directives inside the class; it never generates any `MyClass_str1_set` method for str1 or str2.  I've been through the doc and it looks like this ought to work.  I've also tried putting `%mutable MyClass::str1;` at top level, but that doesn't help either.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that clear from docs and can't test this right now but this might work:

```
// make everything immutable except str2 data member:
%feature("immutable","1");
%feature("immutable","0") MyClass::str2;

class MyClass {
 public:
  char *str1;
  char *str2;
  char *str3;
};
```

If that doesn't work you could also try moving the statement inside the class:

```
class MyClass {
 public:

  // make everything immutable except str2 data member:
  %immutable;   
  char *str0;
  char *str1;

  %mutable;   
  char *str2;

  %immutable;   
  char *str3;
  char *str4;
};
```

Comment: Your first solution works.  One of my problems was that %mutable doesn't work here; you _must_ say `%feature("immutable","0") MyClass::str1`.  And also you have to have that outside the class, at top-level.  Your second solution might work but then I'd have to put `%immutable` in every class, which would be annoying.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @garyo Great to hear, thanks for update. If you don't mind, indicating why no upvote, I may be able to improve answer. Cheers!